# Well now, the election results page looks kinda ugly doesn't it?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I think I'll just leave this here for the overworked design team.
(You guys get it because I was looking at your election page to see what the turnout was like :-)

[image]

We can has line break?

Comment: Fine... I'll change my picture to something that isn't my actual face so the page won't be so ugly. Tough crowd.

Comment: @JeffFerland Done broke my HTML rendering your face did! It's awful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Line break? ***LINE BREAK?!!***

Fine:

[image: unbroken page]
*There's* your precious line break.

Comment: See how easy it is to make the kitty happy?   <- Happy Kitty.

Comment: Your cat appears to be a small square. You should probably talk to a veterinarian.

Comment: Well ***SOMEBODY'S*** browser doesn't support U+1F638

Comment: YOU CAN'T HANDLE THE LINE BREAK

Comment: @BenBrocka . . . Now that you mention it this trivial change may have broken rendering in IE (but I'm not firing up a Windows VM to test :-P)

Comment: @voretaq7 looks fine in IE8 and 9

Comment: @voretaq7 - broke in latest chrome :-)